# Setting Pass/Fail using Python for an automated test in Sauce Labs?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, saucelabs

So, I'm a complete noob when it comes to this kind of thing, and I need some help.  I work in software QA for an ecommerce company, and we started using Saucelabs for our automated testing.  I'm in the process of learning python but really know next to nothing at this point.  I can build a decent test in Selenium IDE, export in Python/Selenium Webdriver, and run the test.  Not an issue.  However, how do I set the pass/fail flag on the interface?  One of our devs wrote a parallel script so I can run a large number of tests at one time, but in order to do so I need to be able to see at a glance which tests have passed and which ones have failed.    Can you help me?  Thanks!

Also, any tutorials you are aware of on Selenium Webdriver would be helpful too!  Really want to learn this stuff!

Comment: I would have thought it follows the standard procedure of most testing frameworks: it's a pass if there are no exceptions or you *explicitly force* it to be passed, and it's a failure if there are any exceptions or you *explicitly force* it to be failed.

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way, first you need to import some things

```
# These next imports for reporting Test status to Sauce Labs
import sys
import httplib
import base64

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Then you need this config

```
#Config to connect to SauceLabs REST API
config = {"username": "yourusernamehere",
          "access-key": "youraccesskeyhere"}
```

Then you put your tests. At the end, before your TearDown you need to include

```
# Curl call to SauceLabs API to report Job Result
    def set_test_status(self, jobid, passed):
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (config['username'], config['access-key']))[:-1]
        body_content = json.dumps({"passed": passed})
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("saucelabs.com")
        connection.request('PUT', '/rest/v1/%s/jobs/%s' % (config['username'], jobid),
                       body_content,
                       headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64string})
        result = connection.getresponse()
        return result.status == 200
```

Then in your tearDown you need to include some kind of *if* logic. I did it this way (and it works)

```
def tearDown(self):
    # sys.exc_info should be (None, None, None) if everything is OK, it fills with some values if something went wrong
    # This if reports to Sauce Labs the outcome of the Test where True = Pass and False = Failed
    if sys.exc_info() == (None, None, None):
        self.set_test_status(self.driver.session_id, True)
    else:
        self.set_test_status(self.driver.session_id, False)
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

That did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sauce labs REST API](https://saucelabs.com/docs/rest) to mark your test pass/failed. You can find some example code given [here](http://support.saucelabs.com/entries/20797798-Updating-pass-fail-status-in-Jobs-using-Selenium-2-and-Java)